# I have to print the measurement with customer name and number

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, printing, android-jetpack-compose

In this code I have to set the pant measurement on right side of the page in one box.

```
override fun onWrite(
        pages: Array<PageRange>?,
        destination: ParcelFileDescriptor?,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?,
        callback: WriteResultCallback?
    ) {
        val output = FileOutputStream(destination?.fileDescriptor)
        val pdfDocument = PdfDocument()
        val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create()
        val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)
        val canvas = page.canvas

        val nameTextView: TextView = content.findViewById(R.id.detailName)
        val numberTextView: TextView = content.findViewById(R.id.detailNumber)

        val paint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.BLACK
            textSize = 18f
        }

        drawBoxWithTitle(canvas, "Customer Print", 50f, 140f, 545f, 750f)
        canvas.drawText("Name: ${nameTextView.text}", 50f, 50f, paint)
        canvas.drawText("Phone Number: ${numberTextView.text}", 50f, 100f, paint)

        drawBoxWithTitle(canvas, "Shirt", 50f, 140f, 545f, 750f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailLength, "Length", 200f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailShoulder, "Shoulder", 250f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailsleeve, "Sleeve", 300f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailcuff, "Cuff", 350f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailchest, "Chest", 400f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailstomach, "Stomach", 450f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailfront, "Front", 500f)

        // Draw rectangle and title for pant measurements on the right side
        drawBoxWithTitle(canvas, "Pant", 350f, 140f, 845f, 750f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detaillengthP, "LengthP", 600f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailwaist, "Waist", 650f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailseatp, "SeatP", 700f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailthigh, "Thigh", 750f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailknee, "Knee", 800f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailbottom, "Bottom", 850f)
        drawMeasurement(canvas, content, R.id.detailround, "Round", 900f)

        pdfDocument.finishPage(page)
        pdfDocument.writeTo(output)

        callback?.onWriteFinished(arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES))
        output.close()
    }
```